# Principal Component Analysis in Python intrinsic dimension map to feature names?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

Objective: Get data from DB to pandas DataFrame, preprocess, run PCA, get intrinsic dimension, use principal features in multi linear regression.

1) I have connected to my MS SQL db and fetched all data from sql stmt to pandas data frame. ---> shape = 54K rows X 90 features (column names)

2) Next, I have preprocessed the data.
3) Next, I have built pipeline to scale, fit, transform the data to StandardScaler and PCA with 20 components.

**Now after building my bar graph of PCA features on X axis and Explained Var on Y axis I see I can use intrinsic dimension 7.
How can I translate 7 to the feature/column names? Does 7 mean take the first 7 columns of my dataframe?
Purpose: Next I will use these columns in my multi linear regression.**

If needed here is what I have done so far:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc


engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@servername/dbname?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
con = engine.connect()

stmt = """Select Col1 ... Col90 from table where Col1 = alpha, ..."""

rs = con.execute(stmt)

df = pd.DataFrame(rs.fetchall())
df.columns = rs.keys()

df_number_columns = df.loc[:,'Age':]

scaler = StandardScaler()
model = PCA(n_components=20)

pipeline = make_pipeline(scaler, model)

df_number_columns = df_number_columns.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

column_names = np.array(rs.keys())
idx_2_start = np.where(column_names == 'Age')[0][0]

df_number_columns.columns = column_names[idx_2_start:]

pipeline.fit_transform(df_number_columns)

features = range(model.n_components_)
plt.bar(features, model.explained_variance_)
plt.xlabel('PCA Feature')
plt.ylabel('Variance')
plt.xticks(features)

plt.show()
```